# how to add woocommerce custom value

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add a custom value to the cart total on $data->cart_totals = WC()->cart->get_totals(); , for this I have created a form field like custom_amount and want to add its value to cart total. It is properly adding to the meta value but I am not able to add it through php on order total.

Answer (score 0):

There's a filter, woocommerce_cart_total, that you could hook into to change the value returned.